# How to insert a file path with tab- or autocompletion relative to the current file's dir?

Tags: autocompletion, filesystem

I am in vim in the `.gitignore` file. I now want to add a file path that already exists on the current dir, e.g.

`./app/poit/narf/auth.json`

I don't want to type it though, I want to navigate to that file somehow with tabcompletion in vim and then insert its filename in the `.gitignore` file.

How can I achieve this?

What I know I can do is open the editor command

`:e app/poit/narf/auth.json`

and I can have tabcompletion here. Yet this only gets me the text in the command window, and now I have to yank it somehow inside the buffer. I am also looking more for a more fit solution.

Answer (score 9):

You can use vim's file name completion feature for this.  To use it, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> in insert mode.  For more on this, see `:help compl-filename`.  Do note that it isn't recursive, so you must complete the path level by level.  *(first `app/`, then `poit/`, etc.)*

Comment: I see a box opening, yet I am unsure how to navigate within it. Ctrl+N and Ctrl+P move up and down, yet I do not understand your "it isn't recursive part". Could you please elaborate on how I can complete a nested file name multiple level down?

Comment: To select items from the list, use the Ctrl+N and Ctrl+P keys, and keep typing to finish the completion.  What I mean by it being non recursive is that you have to complete the path each item at a time, like you would with tab completion in a bash shell.